# Trouble Connecting R Studio to Snowflake on M1 Macbook

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble connecting to ODBC Snowflake in R Studio. Here are my connection settings, and I have installed the Snowflake driver as well as ODBC and I'm on an M1 Mac:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = '/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib',
                      Server = <URL here from work>,
                      UID = <USERNAME>,
                      Trusted_Connection = "True",
                      authenticator = "externalbrowser",
                      Database = <DATABASENAME>)
```

I get the following error message after trying to run:

[image]

Comment: [Can't open lib 'libSnowflake.dylib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69066996/sequeldatabaseconnectionerror-odbcerror-01000-0-unixodbcdriver-manage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by downloading the latest Snowflake ARM driver for Mac, updating the DNS entry (aka odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini) and the syntax in R. Steps are as follows:

Steps:

1. Reinstall latest Snowflake ODBC driver https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/macaarch64/2.25.7/index.html and check that it is ini files are located in /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib
2. Update both ini files to remove "universal" from the driver location Driver = /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/libSnowflake.dylib and also to remove quotations from UID and server
3. Install latest version of ODBC Manager 3.52.15 for arm 64 at https://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads#Stable%20Version%203.52.15
4. Update R connection to the following (includes quotes):

```
    # establish connection
    con <- dbConnect(
    drv = odbc(),
    driver = "/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/libSnowflake.dylib",
    server = "URL",
    uid = "USERNAME",
    authenticator = "externalbrowser",
    role = "SNOWFLAKE_ROLENAME",
    warehouse = "UAT"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to install the ARM version of the library and not the universal one. For example, use snowflake_odbc_mac_arm64-2.25.7.dmg and not snowflake_odbc_mac-2.25.7.dmg